# Python/Numpy if statement syntax

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, if-statement

I have this if statement that checks if an (x,y) randomly generated coordinates are inside the circle, and if so it increments a counter to count how many points are actually inside the circle. 
I have this:

```
    x = numpy.random.uniform(-1, 1, num)
    y = numpy.random.uniform(-1, 1, num)

    if(numpy.all((x**2 + y**2) < 1)):
      c+=1
```

I'm not getting any errors but the if statement is not working, even when I know for sure there are coordinates that make the if statement true. Is my syntax correct here?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: i just realized i need to iterate through both x and y arrays for each element, sorry for being unclear!

Comment: What are x and y? numpy array? If they are numpy array, pretty sure you need `(x ** 2 + y ** 2 < 1).sum()`

Comment: If your program has a runtime bug, the syntax of your program is irrelevant. You should print out the values `x` and `y` to see if their values are what you expected.

Comment: Your description should be: *that checks if **all** (x,y) coordinate is inside the circle*. Are you sure you want to use `.all` instead of `.any`?

Comment: What is the output of `x**2 + y**2`?

Comment: Do you want `(x**2 + y**2) < 1` or `x**2<1` and `y**2 < 1`

Comment: i want to check (x**2 + y**2) < 1. and x and y are randomly generated coordinates

Comment: Are you sure x and y aren't arrays of numbers? This would explain that your if "doesn't work" because if the arrays are large it is very unlikely for all the points they describe to lie inside the circle. Are you by any chance trying to compute pi? Then (if these are arrays) you don't want an if statement but just `c+=((x**2 + y**2) < 1).sum()` This counts how many of the coordinate pairs describe a point inside the circle.

Comment: hi, yes sorry im being so unclear. x and y are both arrays of randomly generated numbers. I just realized i should be going through each element of x and y and doing that if statement. and yes i am trying to compute pi!

Comment: A for loop will work and may even be educational to set up, so go ahead. But ultimately you want to "vectorise". Vectorised code is faster and more readable and therefore considered good practice. You'll find lots of posts on that topic here.

Answer (score 1):

### You can do the same but faster using numpy's vectorised methods:

```
X = np.array([random.uniform(-1,1) for i in range(5)])
Y = np.array([random.uniform(-1,1) for i in range(5)])

# Return Indexes where the statement is true:
L = np.where((X**2 + Y**2) < 1)

print X
print Y
print L

>>>
[-0.91212004  0.65893078 -0.25020712 -0.21768537 -0.99964874]
[-0.06871978 -0.60834897  0.11997134  0.2721608   0.77688788]
(array([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int64),)
```

To return the number of times this occurs simply do:

```
c = len(np.where((X**2 + Y**2) < 1)[0])
c = 4
```

You can then access the elements where this occurred by doing:

```
X_new = np.delete(X,np.where((X**2 + Y**2) < 1)[0],0)
Y_new = np.delete(Y,np.where((X**2 + Y**2) < 1)[0],0)

print X_new
print Y_new

>>>
[-0.91212004  0.65893078 -0.25020712 -0.21768537]
[-0.06871978 -0.60834897  0.11997134  0.2721608]
```

### Original Answer:

If you are checking that the points lie within the radius when `radius = 1` then you can do:

```
X = 0.5
Y = 0.5
c=0
if (X**2 + Y**2) < 1:
    print "Success"
    c+=1
```

In this case, c is just a counter to count the number of times this is true. If you have multiple points in an array you can do:

```
X = [0.5,0.6,0.7]
Y = [0.2,0.3,0.4]
c=0
for x, y in zip(X,Y):
    if (x**2 + y**2) < 1:
        print "Success"
        c+=1
```

For a random number:

```
import random
X = random.uniform(-1, 1)
Y = random.uniform(-1, 1)
c=0
if (X**2 + Y**2) < 1:
    print "Success"
    c+=1
```

And to generate your list of random numbers:

```
import random
X = []
Y = []
for i in range(10):
    X.append(random.uniform(-1, 1))
    Y.append(random.uniform(-1, 1))
c=0
for i,j in zip(X,Y):
    if (i**2 + j**2) < 1:
        print "Yes"
        c+=1
    else:
        print "No"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know how many points out of `num` are inside the unit circle, and want to stick to `NumPy` (which is a good idea), try this:

```
c = ((x**2 + y**2) < 1).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is very vague, it would be helpful if you added more code so we can understand your question better.

But when you say you get no error, and the statement is not working... Then it could be that you are not doing anything with the statement such as giving it a `print()` function.

E.g.

```
import numpy

x = 0.2
y = 0.2
c = 0
if(numpy.all((x**2 + y**2) < 1)):
    c+=1
    print(c)

else:
    print("incorrect")
```

Sorry if I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(numpy.all((x**2 + y**2) < 1)):
```

You don't need outermost parenthesis here, use

```
if numpy.all((x**2 + y**2) < 1):
```

instead.

Comment: It makes no difference whatsoever.